# JCSG difference generates an empty STL. Is this a bug or an error on my part?

Tags: java, 3d, cad

I'm using JCSG with the following code to make triangle with a hole from two polygons (one large and one small). I'm expecting it to look like the attached image but the result is an empty STL.
[image]

```
    List<Vector3d> t1 = new ArrayList<>();
    t1.add(Vector3d.xyz(0, 0, 0));
    t1.add(Vector3d.xyz(100, 0, 0));
    t1.add(Vector3d.xyz(0, 100, 0));

    List<Polygon> poly1 = Polygon.fromConcavePoints(t1);
    CSG csg1 = CSG.fromPolygons(poly1);

    List<Vector3d> t2 = new ArrayList<>();
    t2.add(Vector3d.xyz(10, 10, 0));
    t2.add(Vector3d.xyz(80, 10, 0));
    t2.add(Vector3d.xyz(10, 80, 0));

    List<Polygon> poly2 = Polygon.fromConcavePoints(t2);
    CSG csg2 = CSG.fromPolygons(poly2);

    CSG csg = csg1.difference(csg2);
    String stl = csg.toStlString();
    System.out.println(stl);
```

The result is:
solid v3d.csg
endsolid v3d.csg

Answer (score 0):

JCSG only works on closed surfaces, i.e., it does not work on surfaces without a volume. But there's a trick that you can use to do it anyway:

```
1. extrude your polygons by 1
2. perform the difference operation
3. select all polygons that are in the XY-plane and save them as STL
```

Below is a VRL-Studio sample (screenshot and code) that demonstrates how you can accomplish the difference operation and XY-plane selection in JCSG. The code is Groovy but it is close to Java. All the functionality works in plain JCSG without VRL-Studio as well.

[image: JCSG Difference Operation]

Here's the source code:

**DiffSurface:**

```
import eu.mihosoft.jcsg.Extrude;
import java.util.List;
import eu.mihosoft.jcsg.CSG;
import eu.mihosoft.jcsg.Polygon;
import eu.mihosoft.vvecmath.Transform;
import eu.mihosoft.vvecmath.Vector3d as Vec3d;
import eu.mihosoft.vvecmath.Vectors3d as Vecs;

@ComponentInfo(name="DiffSurface", category="Custom")
@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
public class DiffSurface implements java.io.Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

  // *** DOES NOT WORK (SURFACE IS NOT CLOSED) ***
  public CSG diff1() { 

    List<Vec3d> t1 = new ArrayList<>();
    t1.add(Vec3d.xyz(0, 0, 0));
    t1.add(Vec3d.xyz(100, 0, 0));
    t1.add(Vec3d.xyz(0, 100, 0));

    List<Polygon> poly1 = Polygon.fromConcavePoints(t1);
    CSG csg1 = CSG.fromPolygons(poly1);

    List<Vec3d> t2 = new ArrayList<>();
    t2.add(Vec3d.xyz(10, 10, 0));
    t2.add(Vec3d.xyz(80, 10, 0));
    t2.add(Vec3d.xyz(10, 80, 0));

    List<Polygon> poly2 = Polygon.fromConcavePoints(t2);
    CSG csg2 = CSG.fromPolygons(poly2);

    CSG csg = csg1.difference(csg2);

    return csg

  }

  // *** WORKS (SURFACE CLOSED) ***
  public CSG diff2(double height) { 

    List<Vec3d> t1 = new ArrayList<>();
    t1.add(Vec3d.xyz(0, 0, 0));
    t1.add(Vec3d.xyz(100, 0, 0));
    t1.add(Vec3d.xyz(0, 100, 0));

    // EXTRUDE Triangle 1
    CSG csg1 = Extrude.points(Vec3d.z(height), t1)

    List<Vec3d> t2 = new ArrayList<>();
    t2.add(Vec3d.xyz(10, 10, 0));
    t2.add(Vec3d.xyz(80, 10, 0));
    t2.add(Vec3d.xyz(10, 80, 0));

    // EXTRUDE Triangle 2
    CSG csg2 = Extrude.points(Vec3d.z(height), t2)

    CSG csg = csg1.difference(csg2);

    return csg

  }
}
```

**ReduceToXYPlane:**

```
import eu.mihosoft.jcsg.Extrude;
import java.util.List;
import eu.mihosoft.jcsg.CSG;
import eu.mihosoft.jcsg.Polygon;
import eu.mihosoft.vvecmath.Transform;
import eu.mihosoft.vvecmath.Vector3d as Vec3d;
import eu.mihosoft.vvecmath.Vectors3d as Vecs;

@ComponentInfo(name="Reduce", category="Custom")
public class Reduce implements java.io.Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

  // add your code here

 public CSG reduce(CSG csg) {

  List<Polygon> result = new ArrayList<>();

  // for each polygon in the CSG object
  for (Polygon poly : csg.getPolygons()) {

    // store all vertices in the X,Y plane
    // in a vertex list
    List<Vec3d> vertices = new ArrayList<>();
    poly.vertices.each{v -> 
      if (Math.abs(v.pos.z) < 1e-6) {
        vertices.add(v.pos)
      }
    }

    // if more than 2 vertices are in the list
    // create a polygon and add it to the 
    // polygon list
    if(vertices.size()>2) {
      Polygon p = Polygon.fromPoints(vertices);
      result.add(p)
    }
  }

  // create a CSG from polygons that can be exported
  // as STL
  //
  // NOTE: performing CSG operations on this CSG
  //       will result in invalid computations.
  //       Only use non-closed CSG for converting to STL files
  return CSG.fromPolygons(result);
 }

}
```